# Creating a MySQL Database Schema for large data set

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm struggling to find the best way to build out a structure that will work for my project.  The answer may be simple but I'm struggling due to the massive number of columns or tables, depending on how it's set up.

We have several tools, each that can be run for many customers.  Each tool has a series of questions that populate a database of answers.  After the tool is run, we populate another series of data that is the output of the tool.  We have roughly 10 tools, all populating a spreadsheet of 1500 data points.  Here's where I struggle... each tool can be run multiple times, and many tools share the same data point.  My next project is to build an application that can begin data entry for a tool, but allow import of data that shares the same datapoint for a tool that has already been run.

A simple example:
     Tool 1 - company, numberofusers, numberoflocations, cost
     Tool 2 - company, numberofusers, totalstorage, employeepayrate

So if the same company completed tool 1, I need to be able to populate "numberofusers" (or offer to populate) when they complete tool 2 since it already exists.

I think what it boils down to is, would it be better to create a structure that has 1500 tables, 1 for each data element with additional data around each data element, or to create a single massive table - something like...

customerID(FK), EventID(fk), ToolID(fk), numberofusers, numberoflocations, cost, total storage, employee pay,.....(1500)

If I go this route and have one large table I'm not sure how that will impact performance.  Likewise - how difficult it will be to maintain 1500 tables.

Another dimension is that it would be nice to have a description of each field:
numberofusers,title,description,active(bool). I assume this is only possible if each element is in its own table?

Thoughts?  Suggestions?  Sorry for the lengthy question, new here.

Answer (score 0):

Build a main table with all the common data: company, # users, .. other stuff. Give each row a unique id.

Build a table for each unique tool with the company id from above and any data unique to that implementation. Give each table a primary (unique key) for 'tool use' and 'company'.

This covers the common data in one place, identifies each 'customer' and provides for multiple uses of a given tool for each customer. Every use and customer is trackable and distinct.

More about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with etherbubunny on normalization but with larger datasets there are performance considerations that quickly become important. Joins which are often required in normalized databases to display human readable information can be performance killers on even medium sized tables which is why a lot of data warehouse models use de-normalized datasets for reporting. This is essentially pre-building the joined reporting data into new tables with heavy use of indexing, archiving and partitioning.

In many cases smart use of partitioning on its own can also effectively help reduce the size of the datasets being queried. This usually takes quite a bit of maintenance unless certain parameters remain fixed though.

Ultimately in your case (and most others) I highly recommend building it the way you are able to maintain and understand what is going on and then performing regular performance checks via slow query logs, explain, and performance monitoring tools like percona's tool set. This will give you insight into what is really happening and give you some data to come back here or the MySQL forums with. We can always speculate here but ultimately the real data and your setup will be the driving force behind what is right for you.